# Arranging image thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-hover

I am using JQuery hover zoom (http://jmar.github.com/jquery-hoverZoom/) Its working fine.

The thumbnails that I have is of different sizes . So I stated using the masonry plugin for arranging it.  Both of them work fine when isolated but collectively the masonry plugin doesn't work as intended. Pictures start to overlap each other.

What I feel is that both Masonry and the JQuery hover zoom , interact with the same div element which causes the problem, Both are adding their attributes to it.

How can I fix this ?

Is there some way that I arrange the rows without the masonry? So that the conflict wont occur ?

Comment: css box-model can arrange the elements, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code? It's propably the `z-index` fault. My guess would be setting very high (try 9999 at first, then justify it to your needs) `z-index` value for `.zoomed` (class that is added to element when hovered).